# List of Envelope Documents request does not return envelopeDocuments

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having an issue with the following request:

**/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents**

Request:

```
GET https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCT_ID/envelopes/ENVELOPE-GUID/documents
```

And the response looks like this:

```
{
"envelopeId": "ENVELOPE-GUID"
}
```

That's the full response I get. It does reproduce at least for several envelopes for me. The envelopes in question are all in 'Completed' or 'Awaiting my signature' sate and have been sent from other DocuSign accounts.

If requested using the sender account, I get a normal response containing the **envelopeDocuments** array. Same goes for other recipients accounts present in the envelope. The request for those accounts however uses **www.**docusign.net as the baseUrl based on the login_information response.

This also reproduces if I send from the na2 account and later try to retrieve documents list from the www ones so I would say it's some kind of sharding issue.

The request used to work fine with the same accounts earlier.

Comment: It is a best practice to consistently POST and GET utilizing the same baseURL. I'm surprised you don't receive authentication errors as well. Can you verify the behavior if the POST was www. and the GET is also www.?

Comment: Are you making the call from the Signer account?

Comment: @wtp-api, I'm sorry, but I don't think your comment makes much sense. I use several accounts and thus I get different baseURLs from DocuSign login_information responses. I would get auth exceptions if I used an incorrect baseURL for some account but it is (at least was) completely valid to request envelope documents from any account that has access to it.

Comment: Are you creating envelopes from one account, but requesting the document with credentials from a second account(Signers account)?

Comment: @wtp-api, that's one of the options. Another one is when we get an incoming envelope to our account but have no access to the sender account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a bug and I've filled it as such with DocuSign's support department.**

**Authenticating as the sender will be the only workaround you could do for now.**

**Here's the actual issue:**

1. Create envelope on NA2 and send it to an active account on NA1
2. Run the following call against REST (v2 or vdev, same results) with the Signer's account information

`GET:https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents`

Actual Results:

```
{
 envelopeId: "EnvelopeIdGUID"
}
```

Desired Results:

```
{
  "envelopeId": "EnvelopeIdGUID",
  "envelopeDocuments": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "Document1.pdf",
      "type": "content",
      "uri": "/envelopes/{EnvelopeId}/documents/1",
      "order": "1",
      "pages": "1"
    },
    {
      "documentId": "2",
      "name": "Document2.pdf",
      "type": "content",
      "uri": "/envelopes/{EnvelopeId}/documents/2",
      "order": "2",
      "pages": "1"
    },
    {
      "documentId": "certificate",
      "name": "Summary",
      "type": "summary",
      "uri": "/envelopes/{EnvelopeId}/documents/certificate",
      "order": "999",
      "pages": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```